# how to include dynamic html file in html page in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have set value in variable {action:'page1.html'} after render this value in index.html layout then I want to use include dynamically page but not working.

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

         console.log(req.query.action);
         res.render('users/index', {action:'page1.html'});
    });

**index.html**

<% include+"./"+action %>
```

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must have versione 2.x of EJS, then you need to include it as:

```
<%- include(action) %>
```

Ref: https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes